# putting a text over image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page that displays a series from a table. When I use `foreach` to display all results in the table, it works fine. But the problem appears when I try to put a text over every image. I made the image `position: relative;` and text `position: absolute;` but all texts become the first image only [image].

[fidde link](https://jsfiddle.net/ehx5omfn/)

```
<div class="container maincontainer">
<div class="container ser text-center">
<ul>
<?php
$i=0;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM series ORDER BY added_date DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){ 
echo '
<div class="imgdiv">
<a href="series.php?id=' . $row['seriesID'] .'">
<img class="images" src="'. $dirnam .'cp/uploads/posters/'.$row['poster'].'"></a><div style="position: absolute;z-index:1100;">calc</div>'; ?>
<?php
} ?>
```

css:

```
.images{
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 16.66666%;
    padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#ff0;

}
.series{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;


}


.imgdiv:hover img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.srchbox{
    margin-left: 50px;
    float:right;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.ser{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 36px;
}

.maincontainer{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.65);
}
```

Comment: Where is your opening `<li>` and closing `</div>`? Please open a fiddle or similar so we can see what you have tried exactly...

Comment: Peter Featherstone https://jsfiddle.net/ehx5omfn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those elements has `position: relative`, at least not in the code you posted. So there is no "position anchor" for the absoluteley positioned text elements.

EDIT AFTER COMMENT AND POSTED FIDDLE:

Most of the settings you applied to your images (float, size, relative position etc.) should instead be applied to the `imgdiv` class. The images themselves should just get 100% width and an auto height.

Take a look at this fiddle which contains the solution and tell me if you don't understand something:

https://jsfiddle.net/bn70byh8/1/

Note: If you absolutely want to stretch the image heights to cover their conatiners completely, you can use `height: 100%` on the images. However, this will change the width/height ratio and possibly distort the images.

Comment: thank you but i did what you said and nothing changed : https://jsfiddle.net/ehx5omfn/2/

Comment: please note my changed answer and the included fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

`.images` will need to be given a `position: relative`, which will allow your absolute positioned divs with text to overlay. Here's a great reference!

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/